# should signal() method always be in between lock() and unlock()?

Tags: java, methods, signals

Does a call to `signal()`, `await()`, or `signalAll()` always need to be in between `lock()` and `unlock()`?

Example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;

class A{
    int num=0;
    boolean onoff=false;
    private final ReentrantLock key=new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition setCondi=key.newCondition();

    void input(int i){

        key.lock();
        try{

            if(onoff==true)
                setCondi.await();

            num=i;       
            onoff=true; 
            setCondi.signal();      

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            key.unlock();
        }
            num=i;       
            onoff=true; 
            setCondi.signal();
```

Answer (score 2):

[The Javadoc has the answer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal--)

> **An implementation may (and typically does) require that the current thread hold the lock associated with this `Condition` when this method
>   is called**. Implementations must document this precondition and any
>   actions taken if the lock is not held. **Typically, an exception such
>   as `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown.**

So, yes, in typical implementations, the call to `signal()` (and other `Condition` methods) must be done while holding the `Lock`.